# Javascript change <a> links to fancybox iframe popup is limited to 31 links only

Tags: javascript, iframe, popup, fancybox, limit

I have strange problem that I can't solve.

I have a portfolio style page with small thumbnails and each thumbnail hyperlinks to another page on the same domain.

I have write javascript code to change all the `<a><a/>` links to fancybox links in order to opened in iframe popup.

The original link: `<a class="elementor-post__thumbnail__link" href="https:...">...</a>`

The link after apply js: `<a class="elementor-post__thumbnail__link" href="javascript:;" data-fancybox="" data-type="iframe" data-src="https://...">...</a>`

The problem is that my code, only works for the first 31 thumbnail links

I have place the code on the bottom of the page after the content.

Do you have any ideas for my problem?

This is the page: [Example](https://nicolaslagios.com/%CF%80%CE%B1%CF%81%CE%B1%CE%B3%CE%B3%CE%B5%CE%BB%CE%B9%CE%B1-%CE%BD%CE%B5%CE%B1%CF%82-%CE%B9%CF%83%CF%84%CE%BF%CF%83%CE%B5%CE%BB%CE%B9%CE%B4%CE%B1%CF%82/%CF%85%CE%B3%CE%B5%CE%AF%CE%B1-%CE%BF%CE%BC%CE%BF%CF%81%CF%86%CE%B9%CE%AC/)

And this is the code after the content:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fancyapps/fancybox@3.5.7/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fancyapps/fancybox@3.5.7/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
<script>
var i;
for (i = 0; i < "elementor-post__thumbnail__link".length; i++) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("elementor-post__thumbnail__link")[i].setAttribute("data-fancybox", "");
    document.getElementsByClassName("elementor-post__thumbnail__link")[i].setAttribute("data-type", "iframe");
    var datasrc = document.getElementsByClassName("elementor-post__thumbnail__link")[i].getAttribute("href");
    document.getElementsByClassName('elementor-post__thumbnail__link')[i].setAttribute("data-src", datasrc);
    document.getElementsByClassName("elementor-post__thumbnail__link")[i].setAttribute("href", "javascript:;");
}
</script>
```

Any help is useful. Thanks in advance, Nicolas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always I find the answer myself or they help me from elsewhere.

Anyways, here is the solution:

> Change the line which begins with "for" from this
>
> `for (i = 0; i < "elementor-postthumbnaillink".length; i++) {`
>
> to this

```
for (i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll("a.elementor-post__thumbnail__link").length; i++) {
```

> Your code is only doing it 31 times because your current code
> says to repeat it for the length of the word
> "elementor-postthumbnaillink" which is 31 characters long.

Thanks to tazmeah for this solution on another site.